# Подгрузка содержимого модального окна после его открытия

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Добрый вечер!

Суть моего вопроса, в том, что есть модальное окно, а в нем лежит `iframe`, который подгружает видео из ютуба.

Но подгружает все видео сразу, по открытию страницы, что занимает довольно много времени. А нужно сделать так, чтобы содержимое модального окна (сам iframe) подгружалось только после его открытия.

Код вызова:

```
<a href="#project<?php echo $id ?>">
    <div class="blockwithpf">
        <img alt="<?php echo $program_name ?>" class="" src="images/lightbox/<?php echo $program_name ?>.jpg">
    </div>
</a>
```

Код модального окна:

```
<?php 
    echo '<div class="remodal youtube" data-remodal-id="project'.$id.'" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1Title" aria-describedby="modal1Desc">';
?>          
    <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
    <div>
            <p id="modal1Desc">
            <?php 
                echo '<iframe width="635" height="357" src="'.$youtube_link.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
            ?>
            </p>
            <p id="modal1Title"><?php echo $program_name ?></p>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Собственно нужно, или условие перед вызовом `<iframe width="635" height="357" src="'.$youtube_link.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`или что-то еще.

В исходном коде, когда страница подгрузилась можно увидеть следующее:

```
$(document).on('opened', '.remodal', function () {
            console.log('opened');
          });
```

Возможно ли, вокруг этого сделать условие, "Если opened - тогда подргружаем", было бы замечательно увидеть как это сделать. Также, может быть, у вас есть другие варианты решения этой задачи.

Модальное окно используется вот такое: http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/

Спасибо за ответы и помощь!

Comment: ссылку на iframe добавляйте только когда opened. На сервере ссылку кладите в data-src, а когда будет opened, то достаньте эту ссылку и присвойте iframe. Если честно то я так не делал, но кажется логичным, но если что, то не ругайте меня :)

Comment: мне тоже кажется логичном, но на практике не вышло

Comment: Ещё как вариант - делать `ajax` запрос, получить ваш `iframe` и в `success` выводить в модальное окно.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, надо положить ссылку не в src, а куда-то еще. Например, как предложил OlmerDale к комментарии, в data-src:

```php
<iframe width="635" height="357" data-src="<?=$youtube_link?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

теперь при открытии диалога надо скопировать значение атрибута `data-src` в `src`:

```js
$(document).on('opened', '.remodal', function () {
    $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', getSrc);

    function getSrc() { return $(this).data('src'); }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo '<iframe id="modal_video" style="display:none;" width="635" height="357" src="'.$youtube_link.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

$(document).on('opened', '.remodal', function () {
    $('#modal_video').show();
});
```

Попробуй так, либо меняй сам линк через JS

Comment: Тут проблема тогда не решается, хорошо мы убираем видимость элемента, но все равно в момент загрузки общей страницы все фреймы подгружаются, хоть их и не видно. Если бы было что-то вроде параметра load: no-load - тогда да)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: когда display: none; html не обрабатывает этот блок

Answer (score -1):

Когда то имел похожую задачку только с картинками. Клиент хотел чтобы они загружались после открытия модального окна.

Тогда я просто дописывал кусок HTML кода в модальное окно как только ловил ивент click на открытие. Ссылки на картинки хранились в аттрибуте data-image в теге кнопки на которую был навешен  ивент открытия модального окна.

Возможно такой вариант вам поможет.